# taking the new value of variable when setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion is set

Tags: batch-file

I have a code that compares filestamp with script execution timestamp.
it works if the values are different, however when the values are same, the code still does not go out of the loop.
I am thinking the reason behind this is the statement setlocal enableDelayedExpansion at the start of the script.

The code correctly prints the value of filesstamp and datestamp, However the if logic does not work properly.

```
@ECHO off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

ECHO !fileTimemod!>x&FOR %%? IN (x) DO SET /A strlength=%%~z? - 2&del x
echo filetimelength !strlength!
IF !strlength! EQU 1 (
    SET fileTimemod=0!fileTimemod!
echo fileTimemod !fileTimemod!
)



set FileM=!filestamp:~0,2!
set FileD=!filestamp:~3,2!
set FileY=!filestamp:~6,4!


set filestamp=!FileY!!FileM!!FileD!!final!

echo datestamp !datestamp!
echo filestamp !filestamp!
set newTimestamp=!filestamp!

 if  "!datestamp!" gtr "!filestamp!" (
 echo The file is older than the script execution time.

 ) else (
 echo Read the new file

)
```

```
**Log**
**datestamp 201310071449
filestamp 201310071435**
The file is older than the script execution time.
24 delay
counter value is 1
Checking whether the file  exists in the directory
10/07/2013 02:49 PM
File minutes 49
02
fileAMPM PM
2
filetimelength 1
fileTimemod 2
result 14
final 1449
**datestamp 201310071449
filestamp 201310071449**
The file is older than the script execution time.
24 delay
```

Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should reduce your script to the absolute necessary code to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is the solution not the problem.

You should always use the delayed syntax for variables inside of blocks, as percent expansion will be expanded **before** a block is executed, delayed expansion when a line is executed.

```
IF %strlength% EQU 1 (
  SET dateHMod=0%dateHMod%
  echo dateHMod %dateHMod%
)
echo dateHMod %dateHMod%
```

The two `echo` lines show different outputs, the first without the `0` the next with the `0`.

```
IF !strlength! EQU 1 (
  SET dateHMod=0!dateHMod!
  echo dateHMod !dateHMod!
)
echo dateHMod !dateHMod!
```

This works always as expected.

In your case the problem could also be a hidden space issue.
As your script with your values works as expected.
A hidden space after a `set` command is not visible, but will be appended to the variable, therefor it's always a good idea to use the quote syntax when using `set`, this only assigns all characters up to the last quote.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "datetime=201310071449" This won't be assigned
set "filestamp=201310071449"
echo datestamp -!datestamp!-
echo filestamp -!filestamp!-
set "newTimestamp=!filestamp!"

if  "!datestamp!" gtr "!newTimestamp!" (
    echo The file is older than the script execution time.
) else (
    echo Read the new file
)
```

Comment: I tried changing the % to ! but still it does not work. the timestamps are same but if condition does not work. Try out the whole batch script.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Just by adding " in the echo statement I found out that somehow the filestamp is getting a space at the end.           datestamp "201310071637"
filestamp "201310071634 " I have to now figure out how that space is getting added